# MongoDB Realm: TypeError: user.mongoClient is not a function

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-realm

When I'm calling:

```
const user = await app.logIn(creds);
const mongodb = user.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas");
```

from react-native in an attempt to connect to MongoDB Atlas (`app` is an instance of a Realm App) I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: user.mongoClient is not a function
```

The user is not null and I can call `user.logOut` successfully. I'm not sure where to from here. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is pretty clear; `mongoClient` is not a user object function. Take a look look at the Getting Started Guide[Auth Users](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/authenticate-users/#std-label-react-native-authenticate-users) and then [Open A Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/quick-start/#open-a-realm). The next step is to create a config as shown [sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/sync-changes-between-devices/#pause-or-resume-a-sync-session) to which you can then connect to realm `let realm = await Realm.open(config)`

Comment: @Jay In the docs here, it seems to be including mongoClient: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/query-mongodb/#connect-to-a-linked-cluster

The reason I'm not using sync is that this collection is not very correlated with user data so using a partition on it doesn't make sense (sync requires a partition key). Is that correct reasoning? Or should I sync all collections?

Comment: It is! Did you try app.currentUser.mongoClient(? Also, to clarify using a partition on it - A Realm is a partition and a partition is a Realm - they are the same thing. The documentation is a bit unclear on that point and it uses the two terms interchangeably e.g. when a partitionKey is added to a document, that key defines the Realm the object is part of. And yes, sync requires a partition key; if the data will never be sync'd then it doesn't need a key.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for the clarification! I have tried app.currentUser.mongoClient, but it gave the same error. I thought back to the design of my project, and thought that I should instead have a server rather than serverless (which is what I'm doing right now) because I don't want to be too reliant on MongoDB. This also means that I don't have to deal with this problem anymore! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but for those coming here with the same problem, see my [stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329907/realms-mongodb-user-functions-or-user-callfunction-is-not-a-function) and the opened issue in [realm-js github](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3566).

user.callFunction() and user.mongoClient() are unavailable while debugging using Chrome.

They are not going to fix this because they are working on Hermes engine and Flipper debugging instead.